# Implementation of function

Tags: algorithms, computation-models

We have that MIMA (Neumann MInimal MAchine) has the following commands:

[image]

[image]

I want to implement the Mima-command EQL adr (equal?) with the other Mima-commands.

We have that for that command it holds the following: $$\text{Accu} \leftarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}
-1 , &\text{ Accu }=M(adr)\\ 
0 , &\text{otherwise}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I have done the following:

My idea is to compute -M(adr) and then to add it to Accu, and then to check if it i <0. 
And then to compute the inverse of the result and check if it is <0. 
Is it correct?

```
LCD const 
LDV adr 
NOT 
STV adr 
ADD adr 
STV adr 
JMN x 
LDC -1 
JMP z 
x: LCD 0 
z: NOT 
   JMN m 
   LDC -1 
   JMP n 
   m: LCD 0 
   n: STV adr
```

Is the implementation correct? Could I improve something?

Comment: Programming is offtopic here. Reviewing code for correctness is offtopic everywhere on SE.

Comment: To check the code is the second part of the question... At the first part I am asking how to represent the number in two's complement. @Raphael

Comment: That's why you should ask only one question per post. Please repost the question about the two-complement, but make sure to do some reading and searching on your own before that!

Comment: I created a new post for that: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67706/representation-of-the-number-in-twos-complement @Raphael

Comment: seems reasonably on topic to me wrt Turing completeness. also does this machine have anything to do with von neumann? if so plz provide some bkg on that. is this architecture documented anywhere? do you have a ref?

Comment: It is the machine of von Neumann. Here is a link:  http://gbi.phil-opp.com/folien-ws2014/5.pdf @vzn