# Representation of the number in two's complement

Tags: arithmetic, numeral-representations

We have that MIMA (Neumann MInimal MAchine) has the following commands:

[image]

[image]

I want to write a MIMA program that takes the value $2^{23}-24=8.388.584$ to the memory cell $y$. 
We have to take attention at the number of the bits, that we need for the representation of the number in two's complement.

I have done the following:

We have that $2^{n+1}=2\cdot 2^n=2^n+2^n$.

So, $$2^1=2^0+2^0=1+1 \\ 2^2=2^1+2^1=(1+1)+(1+1) \\ 2^3=2^2+2^2=[(1+1)+(1+1)]+[(1+1)+(1+1)] \\ \text{etc} $$

And we have that $24=2^3\cdot 3=2^3+2^3+2^3$.

We initialize the memory cell $y$ with $1$ and we repeat $23$ times to add the value of $y$ by itself and the result we put it at $y$.

Then we have to subtract three times $2^3$.

How do we do this? Do we have to compute again the $2^3$'s, then compute the inverse and add it to the value that is at $y$ ?

But where do we do these operations? To calculate $2^3$ as above, we have to save the results at each step, or not? But where? Do we consider for that an other memory cell?

Comment: This is more about programming MIMA than actual two's complement...

Comment: Community votes, please: offtopic?

Comment: looks ok to me as exercise in Turing completeness, also would like to know where this architecture is studied in the literature & whether von neumann (cofather of CS) had anything to do with it

Comment: on 2nd look this seems to be a trivial exercise in assembly language concepts. answer: LDC x, STV y. x=$2^{23}-24$. however, different cpus have different n-bit limits on constants, that is not specified here. eg 8 bit processors have a byte limit. if the constant is greater than the operand size then it can be saved over multiple load/stores. & then endian order comes into play. etc

Comment: So, we don't have to write the number first in two's complement? @vzn

Comment: this would relate to assembly code. microprocessors have assembly code which is parsed by an assembler. the assembler typically allows syntax for constants such as decimal, hexadecimal, binary, octal etc... it is possible the assembler for this "cpu" is only conceptual. you can look at assembers for other cpus for example eg "classic/ early" ones like 6502 or 8008 etc. fyi this seems to be called "MISC"/ minimal instruction set computer on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_instruction_set_computer), earliest machine Manchester ~1948. not sure how programs were specified then